# Upgrade from jessie to stretch

Tags: debian, software-installation

I want to ask if this installation process is correct:

I know that mirrors or websites where packages are downloaded are on `/etc/apt/sources.list` so, once updated my Jessie 8.8, I edited `sources.list` to:

```
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

Then it was updated and upgraded. I suppose that's all. I don't have anything important in my notebook so I didn't make a back up.

**Edit**

The reason I changed to Stretch is that many packages can't be updated with Jessie as `R` and `rpy2` (at least in a simple way).

Is this process correct?

Comment: If you are not a computer whizz who needs the source code you don't need the lines beginning deb-src.

Comment: Isn’t there documentation on Debian’s website?

Comment: @arochester thanks a lot. Any simple source to read what is that?

Comment: @JeffSchaller hmm really I don't know. Did you find something? I just did what seems easy and read some blogs.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/installmanual

Comment: and https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/releasenotes

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have amd64, but there should be info over there..thanks

Comment: what is the point of the question? It things are good, they are good, if they are bad, they are bad. They wont magically will get different because a stranger said so in the Internet.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro because they can be fixed, as I am learning I asked..

Comment: @santimirandarp Do please come back *with specific and objective questions*.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro got it..

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro this seems like a pretty specific and objective question. "Is changing my sources to point to stretch the right way of upgrading from jessie?" I really don't understand why this was closed. And it most certainly isn't a request for learning materials!

Comment: @terdon This is describing a simple, documented process in too many places, the OP did it already by the time the question was written, and asking if it is the "correct" process without anything out of ordinary, any error  and *after* it was done. It does not make much sense IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but first make sure your Jessie install is up to date.

First, with your Jessie `sources.list` do `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` and follow through with that process.

When that is complete, change your Jessie `sources.list` to Stretch -

```
sed -i s/jessie/stretch/g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And then update and upgrade

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And then enjoy your new stretchy goodness.